# What word could one use for a person who lies and talks of big money with no real substance

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, american-english

A person who is known of mine talks about such things:

- This spectacle frame is 200 USD, But when I checked online its cost was around 55 USD.
- He has a relative who has financed 100% of city A and 50% of another city B
- One of his uncles was driving a car and met with an accident, the car climbed the first floor of a building, he was so brave that he tied a cloth around his bleeding head, brought his car down, and went to the hospital
- He told me he is working as an interior designer (he is just a 23-year-old male) and when I mentioned some people in the city who have their own shops, he said they are all like villagers and idiots, they don't know anything
- He told me that he will be gifting his father a 54k USD car as a surprise and then after a week he told, me the car would be a depreciating asset, I would rather invest money in business

The above are some exact statements by him. Although I can ignore them as he is just a 23-year-old guy. But still, it's somewhat unusual for someone to make such extreme statements. In fact, the above is just from 1-2 conversations with him and in every conversation, he will throw several such things.
**Not sure what it is called in English.**
Is there any particular word that could describe his behavior?

Comment: He is just an outright liar.

Comment: He's a braggart, a blowhard...

Comment: I assume this has a very specific term in your language...?

Comment: 'All mouth and no trousers', my mother would have said.

Comment: They have an idiom or slang in Texas, USA. "Big hat, no cattle".

Comment: Nowadays Americans might call him a [George Santos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Santos).

Comment: [Synonyms for **braggart**.](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/braggart)

Comment: @stangdon I found that braggart means someone who boasts about his achievements. But in this case the thing he is talking about are lies, he hasn't achieved anything

Answer (score 1):

A slang word springs to mind: fronting.  "Putting up a front" would be more standard English .

Comment: Interestingly the word `fronting`  appears under https://www.urbandictionary.com/ Does it mean that it's not yet added to standard dictionaries like oxford, and Cambridge but has been used by people in daily language?